# Can't deploy worker on heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku

I'm trying to add heroku worker but couldn't find a way.

[This is a Procfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u4NN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewJiH.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post configuration, errors, etc., as **text**, not pictures. Please also take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [scale your Heroku Dynos formation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling#manual-scaling).

Try this:

```
heroku ps:scale web=0 worker=1
```